# Trouble using XmlTextWriter with MemoryStreams

Tags: c#, xml, stream, httphandler

I'm having trouble getting a memory stream and a XML text writer class to work together properly.

```
Context.Reponse.BufferOutput=true;
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
stmOutput = new MemoryStream();
Output = new XmlTextWriter(stmOutput, Encoding.ASCII);
Output.WriteStartDocument();
Output.WriteStartElement("MyTag");
Output.WriteEndElement();
Output.WriteEndDocument();
Output.Flush();
stmOutput.Flush(); 
Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(stmOutput.ToArray(),0,(int)stmOutput.Length-1);
Context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Output.Close();
```

This is being done inside an ASHX file. When I run this, all that gets output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?><MyTag /
```

Am I missing something with Response, or the memory stream or the XML text writer? I'm kinda lost because I'm following a little guide to it doing everything it shows but instead using a memory stream, and its not working. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to remove the `-1` in `Length`? I think the only thing missing in the output is a `">"`.

```
Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(stmOutput.ToArray(), 0, (int)stmOutput.Length);
```